# jQuery - using ( html, attributes, context ) in one function

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

I'm trying to create a separate  `$$` function for like a *iframe scope* and to do that I need to use the function like this, this is what I have tried

**HTML:**

```
<iframe src="" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

**JAVASCRIPT:**

```
var $$ = function( html, attributes ) {
    var context = $('iframe')[0].contentDocment;
    return $(html, attributes, context);
}
```

**Usage**:

```
$$('<h1>', {text: 'Hello'}).appendTo('body');
```

So I **should** end up with this result

```
<iframe src="" frameborder="0">
   #Document
      <html>
         <head></head>
         <body>
            <h1> Hello </h1>
         </body>
      </html>
</iframe>
```

But instead I end up with this result.

```
<iframe src="" frameborder="0"></iframe>
<h1> Hello </h1>
```

Any Advice?

**JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/77VED/1**

Comment: Your problem is the `appendTo('body')`. The `body` selector will not be executed in the iframe context. You could try `appendTo($$('body'))`, but I'd recommend to load another instance of jQuery into the iframe and use that.

Comment: FYI, the third argument to `$` is ignored: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery2.

Comment: How can i load another instance of jQuery into the iframe, and at the same time be able to use both?

Comment: Does the fact that contentDocment is spelled incorrectly matter at all...

Comment: @Phix No, but good spot, thanks

Answer (score 0):

How bout simply doing something like this?

```
$("iframe").contents().find("body").html('YOURCONTENT');
or
$('<h1>', {text: 'Hello'}).appendTo($('iframe').contents().find('body'));
```

Btw. this is a possible duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1390384/jquery-how-to-append-object-to-iframe-in-webkit-based-browsers-chrome-safari)

Comment: It's not a duplicate, you seem to be missing the point. I know how to add content to a `iframe`.

Comment: no it doesn't make sense in any other way, cause the appendTo is which needs to hold the context, the selector itself is not the problem.

Comment: The point is - the function needs to act like a scope and therefore be **dynamic**

Comment: I think I get what you mean, but from my understanding appendTo is just appending "SOMETHING", defined by the previous selector, to "SOMEWHERE" the scope hereby would be needed for "SOMEWHERE" so inside appendTo. It would be something different if you would use "append()" or "html()"