# Open all Joomla 2.5 links within dialog/modal only as "component"?

Tags: jquery, joomla, modal-dialog, joomla2.5, colorbox

So I have a specific page that spawns a modal dialog to login/register when the page loads. I am using Colorbox, and this is working nicely for me. What I need to do is open ONLY the form and not the entire page with header links and such. I understand this can be fixed by adding '?tmpl=component' or '&tmpl=component' to the end of the url. So, the direct link I am using is correctly working but if the user clicks any other links within the dialog...the following pages are no longer "component" pages. I've tried using "if colorbox is visible" and going from there,

```
if ($("#colorbox").css("display")=="block") {  
    alert('ColorBox is currently open');  
}else{  
    alert('ColorBox is currently closed');  
}
```

but when the colorbox is open...the alert does not fire. So, any link that is being viewed within the colorbox/while the colorbox is open the url should have ?tmpl=component appended to the end. Below is how I have the colorbox set to spawn. Automatically, and I've tried using the onLoad and onOpen callbacks with no luck. Any ideas?

**HTML:**

`<a class="iframe cboxElement" href="/login-custom/log-in?tmpl=component" title="Please log in to view subscriptions." style="display: none;">Login Modal</a>`

**jQuery:**

```
$(".iframe").colorbox({
  iframe:true, 
  width:"80%", 
  height:"80%", 
  open: true, 
  closeButton: true, 
  overlayClose: false, 
  escKey: false, 
  onCleanup: function() {       
    window.parent.location.reload();
  }

});
```

Comment: I'd suggest two things: Either append via jquery the `?tmpl=component` to all `href` of the links inside your iframe ([this might be of help](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1390384/jquery-how-to-append-object-to-iframe-in-webkit-based-browsers-chrome-safari)) Or you can set a barebones -like the `component`- template as default and assign the normal template of your site to menu items or something like that.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, got it figured out. First thing I was doing wrong was trying to edit code in the main page - index.php. Since I want the component version of these pages, I needed to edit the component.php (public_html/templates/system/component.php) with the following:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){
      jQuery('a').each(function() { 
          var symbol= '?';
          var url= jQuery(this).attr('href');
          if(url.indexOf('?')>-1) { symbol='&' }
          jQuery(this).attr('href', url+symbol+'tmpl=component') 
      });
  });
</script>
```

...BUT that's not all. The component pages do not include the jQuery script to make this work. I added this by:

```
<?php
$doc->addScript('https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.min.js');
$doc->addScriptDeclaration('if ( typeof jQuery == "undefined" ) document.write(\'<script src="core/js/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"><\/script>\');');
?>
```